# Hypergeometric distribution- problem with derivation

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, combinatorics, hypergeometric-distribution

A random variable $K$ has hypergeometric distribution with parameters $N, m, n$, with probability mass function:
$$
p_K(k)=\frac{\binom{m}{k}\binom{N-m}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}},\quad k\in\{\max(0,n+m-N),\ldots,\min(n,m)\}\quad,
$$
$N$ is a population size,  $m$ and $N-m$- sizes of two disjoint subsets of population (name them $A$ and $B$). The numerator  indicates the number of $n$-element subsets, which contain $k$ elements choosen from $A$, and $n-k$ elements from $B$. I know the deriviation  of this formula, however, i tried to do it in another way, and result is not correct. I would like to find out, where my reasoning fails. Suppose we firstly count a number of $n$-element sequences, in which we have on first $k$ places elements from $A$, and on the rest $n-k$ places elements of $B$. Then we divide this amount by a count of permutation to achieve figure of $n$-element subsets of population, with exactly $k$ elements from $A$ and $n-k$ elements of $B$:
$$
\frac{\underbrace{m\times(m-1)\times\ldots\times(m-k+1)}_{k\ elements}\underbrace{(N-m)\times(N-m-1)\times\ldots\times(N-m-(n-k)+1)}_{n-k\ elements}}{n!}\\=\frac{m!}{(m-k)!}\frac{(N-m)!}{(N-m-(n-k))!}\frac{1}{n!}=\frac{\binom{m}{k}k!\binom{N-m}{n-k}(n-k)!}{n!}\ne \binom{m}{k}\binom{N-m}{n-k}\quad.
$$
What is wrong with my derivation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your numerator $$\frac{m!}{(m-k)!}\frac{(N-m)!}{(N-m-(n-k))!}$$
is the number of $n$-element sequences, in which we have on first $k$ places elements from $A$, and on the rest $n−k$ places elements of $B$. And in which *the order matters*, i.e. $(a_1,a_2,a_3,b_1,b_2)$ and $(a_1,a_3,a_2,b_2,b_1)$ are distinct $k+(n-k)$-element sequences.

You can't divide by $n!$ "to achieve figure of n-element subsets of population, with exactly k elements from A and n−k elements of B", because your sequence is splitted into two distinct subsequences, and you have $k!$ permutations in the first subsequence and $(n-k)!$ permutations in the second one. To count the $n$-element subsets with exactly $k$ elements from $A$, *followed by* $(n-k)$ elements from $B$, you must divide by $k!(n-k)!$.

A simple example. Let's say that $n=4$ and $k=2$. A single sequence may be:
$$a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$$
There are $n!=4!=24$ permutations, e.g.
$$a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2;\quad a_2,a_1,b_1,b_2;\quad a_1,a_2,b_2,b_1\quad a_2,a_1,b_2,b_1\tag{1}$$
but also:
$$b_1,a_2,b_2,a_1;\quad b_1,b_2,a_1,a_2;\quad etc.\tag{2}$$
In (2) you *do not* have $k=2$ elements of $A$ followed by $n-k=2$ elements of B, as you have in (1), and the number of permutations in (1) is just $k!(n-k)!=2\times 2=4$: the number of permutations of $k$ elements of $A$, multiplied by the number of permutations of the following $n-k$ elements of $B$.

When you divide by $k!(n-k)!$ you get the number of $n$-elements subsets where the order does not matter:
$$\frac{m!}{(m-k)!k!}\frac{(N-m)!}{(N-m-(n-k))!(n-k)!}=\binom{m}{k}\binom{N-m}{n-k}$$

But this is still the "number of favorable cases", where $k$ is fixed. To get its probability you have to divide it by the "number of all cases possibile", which is $\binom{N}{n}$.

Comment: Some problems with your answer, e.g., ${m\choose k}\ne m(m-1)\cdots (m-k+1)$.

Comment: Ops! I was a bit hasty :)

Comment: @DedekindCuts Thanks!

Comment: @Sergio thank you for your time and answer! However, further i have a problem to understand, why it's wrong to divide by $n!$- an amout of permutations on "whole" sequcence. Could you clarify, why it fails, when i have "two distinct subsequences"? I think my misunderstanding is an effect of lack of knowledge about some elementary, combinatorics fact.

Comment: @Mentossinho Ok. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Sergio so the key point here is that on starting point in this problem i'm interested in amount of sequences, which have on first $k$ places elements of A, and elements of B on the rest $n-k$. That's why we must divide by a figure of this particular class of sequences. If i would like to divide by $n!$, i should start from the amount of "all kinds" of sequences, which is $\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{k}k!\binom{N-m}{n-k}(n-k)!$. Do i understand it correctly?

Comment: @Mentossinho The amount of "all kinds of $n$-sequences" is $\binom{N}{n}$ if the order doesn't matter, $n!$ if the order matters. Dividing by $k!(n-k)!$ is the same trick as computing "$n$-element sequences, in which we have on first $k$ places elements from $A$, and on the rest $n−k$ places elements of $B$" by $m(m-1)\dots$ [$k$ elements] times $(N-m)(N-m-1)\dots$ [$n-k$ elements].

Comment: Sorry: the amount of all kind of $n$-sequences is $N!/(N-n)!$ if the order matters.

Comment: @Sergio sorry, in my previous comment i meant all n-sequences with $k$ elements from A and $n-k$ elements from B, no matter where they are; then dividing by $n!$ give me $n$-element subsets with $k$ elements from A and $n-k$ elements from B.

Comment: @Mentossinho ... but not $n$-element subsets with $k$ elements from $A$ *followed by* $n-k$ elements from $B$.

Comment: @Sergio thank you for your help, i accept the solution :)

Comment: @Sergio i see it, if i am interested in particular kind of sequences, here these with first $k$ elements from A and rest from B, to achieve subsets (where order doesn't matter), i divide the amount of these sequences by the amount of their permutations ($k!(n-k)!$); but if would start from all sequences with $k$ elements from A and $n-k$ from B (the amount is $\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{k}k!\binom{N-m}{n-k}(n-k)!$), then i should divide by its number of permutation ($n!$), to achieve amount of subsets (where order doesn't matter).